# Is it possible to use Windows Hello for an application level biometric authentication?

Tags: authentication, biometrics, facial-identification, windows-hello

I am tasked to create a desktop app with biometric authentication. Since the app will always be running on Windows 10 on a Surface Pro, I looked into Windows Hello and Facial Recognition. After some research it appears that Windows Hello biometric authentication can only be used at the account and not an application level because you can only create one biometric profile per user account. If that's the case what are my alternative options for biometric authentication, I am specifically interested in Facial biometric authentication. Thanks